# C++ : Program crashes when using a set method

Tags: c++

So basically I'm trying to fill my array with some data but apparently I'm doing a mistake .
The problem was when using the method setName() . Somehow the program crashes afterwards . What am I doing wrong here ?

This is my program :

```
using namespace std;
class CEvent
{
public:
    CEvent() = default;
    ~CEvent(){};
    void setName(string str){Name = str;}
    string getName(){return Name;}

private:
    string Name;
};

class CBlock
{
public:
    CBlock() = default;
    friend class CBooking;
    ~CBlock(){}

private:
    CEvent *Schedule[7][5];
};

class CBooking
{
public:
    CBooking() = default;
    void test();
    ~CBooking(){}

private:
    CBlock *Sched;
};

void CBooking::test()  
{ 
   Sched->Schedule[3][2] = new CEvent();
   Sched->Schedule[3][2]->setName("test");      //Problem here 
   cout << Sched->Schedule[3][2]->getName();  
}


int main()
{
    CBooking a;
    a.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `Sched` was never initialized to point to anything! The line `Sched->Schedule[3][2] = new CEvent();` is also liable to segfault, you may have gotten lucky. Your fix might be:

```cpp
CBooking() : Sched(new CBlock()) {}
```

for example.

Comment: Exactly that's what confused me . It was in some cases working and didn't know why . Thanks

Comment: Also have to allocate memory for   CEvent *Schedule[7][5]   in CBlock

Comment: Also, since `Sched` is being initialised to point at a single (dynamically allocated) `CBlock` there is no need for `Sched` to be a pointer.   An instance can be a member directly, and that member does not need to be initialised using a `new` expression.     You're using C++, so using techniques from C# or Java are unnecessary.   Same comment goes for the `Schedule` member of `CBlock` - no need for the array to contain pointers.